# How to unsort a sorted Column in sap.ui.table?

Tags: xml, sapui5, columnsorting

I have created a table using sap.ui.table. I have created sorting and filtering options for the column. But there is no button/option for unsorting a sorted column either ascending or descending.

Is there any property which allows to unsort a column in sap.ui.table as I don't want to create a function for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "clear sorting" button for table.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Sorting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to sort the table with null to remove any existing Sorters on your binding. Assuming you have your have table as oTable the code would be the following:

```
oTable.getBinding().sort(null);
```